# Strict NAT in Torchlight 2 & Dead Space 3

Tags: technical-issues, torchlight-2, networking, dead-space-3

In both Torchlight 2 and Dead Space 3 I get the message "Strict NAT Detected". I can play online in Torchlight 2 but it's slow. Dead Space 3 can't connect to other players at all.

I've forwarded the ports posted by EA for Dead Space 3 ([source](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Dead-Space-3/Dead-Space-3-NAT-Type-Strict/m-p/476488#M561)):

```
TCP: 80, 443, 9988, 20000-20100, 22990, 17502, 42127    
UDP: 3659, 14000-14016, 22990-23006, 25200-25300
```

I also forwarded the ports posted on [portforwarding.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Thomson-Alcatel/TG789vn/Dead_Space_3.htm)

In Torchlight 2's local settings file I've also added a UDP PORT.
(C:\Documents and Settings\Username\My Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2)

Both games are allowed through the Windows Firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials. 
UpNp is activated and I have the Thomson-Alcatel TG789vn router.

I tried using 3G with internet sharing using my iPhone and the errors are gone, though I can't use it since it's too slow.

Still I get the message in both games. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Could there be any other firewalls in use? For example, usb internet modems sometimes have firewalls built into them as part of the internet providers software.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: There are some [great tips posted by Rockstar games](http://support.rockstargames.com/entries/479758-Understanding-how-NAT-types-affect-online-connectivity). Can you try what they suggest? However, I would not recommend putting your computer in DMZ since that poses a security risk.

Comment: Also, did you add those ports through your router configuration page, or just on your local PC? The Thomson router appears to have a very fleshed-out page for configuring it, which I'm seeing in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXQrIBSaUX8&t=3m30s).

Comment: @SadlyNot I forwarded those ports on the router.

Comment: Who is your ISP?

Comment: Telia, Sweden. Though I don't think that's the problem since it works when using 3G, which is also through Telia.

Comment: You've done everything recommended in [some forums I've read](http://www.sweclockers.com/forum/14-internet-uppkoppling-och-natverk/1135005-open-nat-type-pa-thomson-tg784-hur/), including having one of Telia's newer routers and following the port forwarding guide specific to your router. If somehow you don't have the latest firmware that's all I can think of recommending now.

Comment: It should've been updated about a week ago, how can I see the current & latest firmware?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10213/discussion-between-sadly-not-and-oskar-persson)

Comment: If it works over 3G but not over wired, that's very strong evidence it is your ISP *(even if your ISP is the same for both connections - they likely have different rules for their cell-phone and wired services)*

Answer (score 2):

There is a good possibility you are receiving the strict NAT type because of your service provider. 
I used to have strict NAT on everything I played and when I moved and got a new provider with no changes everything says open NAT now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try DMZ briefly to see if that fixes the performance in Torchlight 2. It is possible that your network performance issues are not related to this problem for Torchlight 2.

For Dead Space 3, I don't have an answer to provide.

Note that using DMZ is a potential security vulnerability so if you have to use it, you should only turn it on when necessary.